# Copying files into multiple directories either throwing exception of overwriting directories

Tags: java

The Code: http://pastebin.com/mKmpX4MY

The Setting:

I have one folder with about 1000 epub files. They all follow the format

AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName - Title.epub

and for the cover art

AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName - Title.jpeg

Sometimes authors colaborate and the filename follows this format

AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName & SecondAuthorFirstname ScondAuthorLastName - Title.epub

Some authors write multiple books so it might look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7LVB.png

What I want to do is have the script copy the books from the same author into a directory named after that author. Every book should be in a directory named after the respective author(s). If they colaborated, they get their own folder.
The ArrayList oldAuthorDirectories lists the paths of the source location and the ArrayList newAuthorDirectores lists the paths of the new directories (You'll notice on line 61 I added a "\" to the end of the new path as I want the files to copy into those directories).
Everything works except for the following and I've been ripping my hair out over it.

If I use the REPLACE_EXSISTING option the copy function replaces the directories with epub files containing just the author without an extension.
If I don't use it it throws an File Exsisting exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reduce this down to a couple strings, and a path operation? Also you really shouldn't be using "\\", the java api should take care of that for you.

Comment: First, make something which verifiably prints _everything_ you want to do without doing it, so you can see what it intends to do (print paths, etc). Using java for this kind of job can be a bit sketch, _especially_ if removing files as it's permanent.

Comment: I've commented the copying out and added the following code above it 


     System.out.println("Copy: " + oldAuthorDirectories.get(y) + " into " + newAuthorDirectores.get(i)); 


This prints the following out: 
     Copy: C:\Users\Daniel\Dropbox\eBooks\Calibre Lib\William Golding - Lord of the Flies.epub into C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\New folder\William Gibson 


As far as I can tell it should work as expected, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the following error.

The destination path requires the file name. Instead of

```
C:/Desktop/Author
```

it has to be

```
C:/Desktop/Author/Author - title.epub
```